# Most efficient way to search for "en.m" links in open questions

Tags: support, search

Assume that I wish to search for en.m.wikipedia links.

> What is the most efficient way to do so?

The following two options didn't work nicely for me:

- Searching for `en.m.` or `"en.m"` yields zero results through the site search, when there are actually such posts.
- Google - on searching `"en.m" site:xyz.stackexchange.com` - yields the correct posts. However, it is unable to differentiate between closed and open questions. Doing `"en m" -closed site:xyz.stackexchange.com` excludes closed questions, but also excludes open questions where the word "closed" is mentioned instead.

Answer (score 6):

`url:en.m.wikipedia.org` seems to work on site search. Naturally you can probably add the appropriate additional arguments as needed. The url: search criteria also covers links, which is much more handy than a plain string search.

Here's an example - naturally from Super User - where I've tried this [search argument](https://superuser.com/search?q=url%3Aen.m.wikipedia.org)

Comment: If I type `url:en.m.wikipedia.org closed:yes` it gives zero results. If I type `url:en.m.wikipedia.org closed:no` it gives 5 results. If I type `url:en.m.wikipedia.org` gives me 130 results. Is there some problem?

Comment: that's a good question - Might be cause many of these are in *answers?* Its much more likely to reference wikipedia in an answer than a question.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks!

Comment: Yup - is:question gives me 5. is:answer gives me 125.

Comment: I never knew the `url` parameter existed, and now my question just seems to be "How do I search for links on SE?" lol :P I'm surprised I still can't find the FAQ post for this though...

Comment: Amusingly, I remembered this off another post I saw the other day.  You can find this under "advanced search tips" though.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it's inside that section.